# How to load config json as environment variable nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am a newbie to node js. I have different configs for different environments viz dev, prod etc. Currently while creating my app package I copy .json to config.json and then export config.json as config variable (global) and use it throughout the app.

`config = require(__dirname + '/config/config');
(config.httpProxy && config.httpProxy.enabled);`

I want to load specific env.json as part of environment variable (for dev dev.json's all keys are exported as global variable in app) instead of copying it into app's config.json, so that same app can be used in different env. How to do that.

PS: for application packaging support and dependency management I use gulp and npm.

Please help.

Comment: Set a variable in each environment to help identify it and determine which file to load. One such standard is to set `NODE_ENV`, accessible with `process.env.NODE_ENV`.

Comment: Thanks Marty. Do you have some code example?

Comment: Yes, see the last part of my comment above.

Answer (score 1):

you can name your files like this:

```
config.development.json
config.production.json
config.test.json
```

Then load files as:

```
config = require(__dirname + '/config/config.' + process.env.NODE_ENV);
```

where process.env.NODE_ENV value can be development/production/test

you have to start your application as

```
NODE_ENV=development node app.js
```

for this to work.

Comment: You're missing something.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your project from your script then set NODE_ENV into your package.json file.

```
    {
       ...
      "scripts": {
        "nodemon:server": "NODE_ENV=dev NODE_PATH=. nodemon --exec \"babel-node --stage 1\" server.js",
         "prod:server": "NODE_ENV=prod NODE_PATH=. nodemon --exec \"babel-node --stage 1\" server.js"

      },
      "author": "'Shubham Batra'",
      "license": "MIT",
      ....
    }
```

```
"prod:server": "**NODE_ENV=prod** NODE_PATH=. nodemon --exec \"babel-node --stage 1\" server.js"
```

than use in config,js file e.g.

```js
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test' ) {
    url = 'http://abc:3000';
    dbUrl= 'xyz';
    password = '***';

} else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'prod') {
    url = 'http://def:3000';
   ...
}
export default {

  conf: {
   url,
    dbUrl,
   ...
   }
}
```

after that, you can import this config file anywhere in your project and use conf

Comment: HI Shubham, Thanks for the answer. However I am holding back myself from loading configs using conditional blocks and looking for something to be done at config level only. The whole idea is to make minimal/ no modification is the app and same app can be deployed in diff environments using different configs.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use this module called config it handles all your env config files. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/config

Just make a folder named config and makes files in it as :

```
1. development.json
2. qa.json
3. production.json
```

While starting server provide relevant environment as others mentioned. 
Then you can use any property mentioned in your config files.

Comment: Thanks, I use the same model currently. However, I need to put all configs outside app.

Comment: If you are willing to use memecached or redis, you can store all configs into them as these store key-value pair. Access all your configurations from there. 

This way you will have to keep only connection details of your redis/memcached in your application. 

You won't have to worry about performance issues, these are very fast and also reliable stores for such key value data.

Comment: Yes, but again I need to hook cache config in app. I am trying to separate config from app completely so that same app can be deployed anywhere by injecting different configs.

Comment: Well, I am not sure how good of an idea it is or it's even secure or not. But I am aware that we can pass multiple variables while starting up an node application. Maybe you could pass the config of cache alongside your environment variable. You might want to take a look at this library : https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs

For more details you might want to check: http://yargs.js.org

You could use it's simplest form in your case. Whatever it is you decide, please mention it. Thanks  :)